# Alternative Solution for Cubic Equation

Tags: roots, cubics

I was solving a problem and got to the following equation $x^3 + x^2 + x - 1 = 0  \; \; (1)$, numerically I found that the solution was:
$$x =\frac{1}{3} \left(-1 - \frac{2}{\left(17 + 3 \sqrt{33} \right)^{-1/3}} + \big(17 + 3 \sqrt{33} \big)^{-1/3} \right)$$

Which gives the same result as the professor. However, I'm suppose to write the solution of (1) as:

$$x = \frac{1}{3} \left(-1 -2\sqrt{2}\sinh\left( \frac{1}{3} \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{17}{2\sqrt{2}}\right) \right)\right)$$

How I do get this expression?

Comment: For clarity, what does $sh$ stand for?

Comment: $\mathcal sh$ is the hyperbolic sine

Comment: To work backwards from the given result: try converting the functions $\sinh(a)$ and $\sinh^{-1}(b/c)$ to the exponential forms and combining them.  I have no idea how you would work forwards from your result perhaps you can kid your professor you did it the hard way somehow.

Comment: Rather than clearly admitting you worked backwards you can always do what many mathematicians seem to do: "Remembering the [standard] identity 'such and such' involving the exponential forms of the hyperbolic functions we can now write:". This seems to be a popular phraseology because it makes you appear hardworking with a good memory, and finesses the problem of being seen to crudely work backwards from the given result.

Comment: The two expressions you have given do not have the same numerical value. If the second one is correct, then the first one is wrong, and in which case the powers on the brackets would have to be $+\frac13$ not $-\frac13$

Comment: Two other alternative solutions $x=\frac{1}{2} \Big(5-\sqrt{33}-\frac{66 (17-3 \sqrt{33})}{99-17 \sqrt{33}+2 \sqrt[3]{33 (99-17 \sqrt{33})}}\Big)$ and $x=\frac{1}{2} \Big(5-\sqrt{33}+\frac{2\cdot 66^{2/3}}{2^{2/3} \sqrt[6]{33}+\sqrt[3]{1683+293 \sqrt{33}}}\Big)$

Comment: @DavidQuinn The exercise is in a book, the numeric result  I got is like $\approx 0,5437$ and that is value given by the solution. However, I'm supposed to get that expression.
As Claude Leibovici pointed up, there might be a typo in the exercise sheet, I'm going to the calculation and then I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I shall follow the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).*

We have $\Delta=-44$ so only one real root.

Using $p=\frac 23$, $q=-\frac{34}{27}$ and the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root)
$$t_0=\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{17}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
$$x=t_0-\frac b {3a}=\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2 \sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{17}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)$$

I suppose that you have a sign error in what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but how do you get to the value of $\Delta$, $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @RFeynman. Did you read the linked Wikipedia page ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the link. I'm going to read it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, you were right! Thank you very much for your help!